# Variadic macros with zero arguments doesn't compile even with ##__VA_ARGS__

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

If I try to compile the following code:

```
template <typename... TArgs>
void Dummy(const TArgs &...args)
{
}

#define DUMMY(...) Dummy("Hello", ##__VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    DUMMY();
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -Wall main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:48: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
    6 | #define DUMMY(...) Dummy("Hello", ##__VA_ARGS__)
      |                                                ^
main.cpp:10:5: note: in expansion of macro 'DUMMY'
   10 |     DUMMY();
      |     ^~~~~
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9217ba86e7d24bd

The code compiles fine when I add at least one parameter:

```
template <typename... TArgs>
void Dummy(const TArgs &...args)
{
}

#define DUMMY(dummy, ...) Dummy(dummy, ##__VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    DUMMY(); // This is strange. Why does this compile?
    DUMMY(1);
    DUMMY(1, 2);
    DUMMY(1, 2, 3);
}
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e30e14810d70f482

But I'm not sure that it is correct, because `DUMMY` takes at least one parameter, but I pass zero.

Comment: I recommend that you stop after preprocessing to see what the macros actually expands to.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, `Dummy("Hello",);` :( [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e7c1f9ef7e63de1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An important fact about C/C++ macros is that it is impossible to invoke them with no parameters, because a macro parameter is allowed to be an empty token sequence.

Consequently, `DUMMY()` invokes the macro `DUMMY` with a single empty parameter, not with zero parameters. This explains why the second example works, and it also explains why the first example produces a syntax error.

The GCC extension deletes the comma from `, ##__VA_ARGS__` when `__VA_ARGS__` has no elements. But a single empty argument is not the same as no arguments. When you define `DUMMY` as `#define DUMMY(...)` , you are guaranteeing that `__VA_ARGS__` has at least one argument, so the `,` won't be deleted.

***Note: GCC does make an exception to that rule if you don't specify some ISO standard with the `--std` option. In that case, if `...` is the only macro parameter and the invocation has an empty argument, then `,##__VA_ARGS__` *does* drop the comma. This is noted in the [CPP manual in the Variadic Marcos section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros):

> The above explanation is ambiguous about the case where the only macro parameter is a variable arguments parameter, as it is meaningless to try to distinguish whether no argument at all is an empty argument or a missing argument. CPP retains the comma when conforming to a specific C standard. Otherwise the comma is dropped as an extension to the standard.

When `DUMMY` is `#define DUMMY(x, ...)`, `__VA_ARGS` will be empty if `DUMMY` is invoked with only one argument, which includes both the invocations `DUMMY()` (one empty argument) and `DUMMY(0)` (one argument, `0`). Note that standard C, and C++ until C++20, would not allow this invocation; they require that there be at least one (possibly empty) argument corresponding to the ellipsis. GCC never imposed this restriction, though, and GCC will omit the comma with `,##__VA_ARGS__`   regardless of the `--std` setting.

Starting with C++20, you can use the `__VA_OPT__` built-in macro as a more standard way of dealing with commas (and any other punctuation which might need to be deleted). `__VA_OPT__` also avoids the problem presented above with empty arguments, because it uses a different criterion: `__VA_OPT__(x)` expands to `x` if `__VA_ARGS__` contains at least one token; otherwise, it expands to an empty sequence. Consequently, `__VA_OPT__` would work as expected for the macros in this question.

I believe that all major compilers now implement `__VA_OPT__`, at least in their recent versions.

Comment: Why then, when you enable `--std=gnu++17`, _gcc_ considers `DUMMY()` as no arguments instead of one empty argument, and removes comma before `##__VA_ARGS__`? See compilation example on [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78e71e0cf4fa5ab3).

Comment: @anton_rh: GCC has a specific exception for the case where the only argument is empty and the --std option indicates gnu. It's at the end of the documentation. I'll make a note in the answer. (I'd never noticed that before because I never compile with --std=gnu anything. Sorry.)

Answer (score 3):

Standard `__VA_ARGS__` doesn't remove trailing `,` when using zero arguments. Your `##__VA_ARGS__` which removes extra `,` is an GCC extension.

This GCC extension doesn't work because you are using standard compatible mode `-std=c++17`, instead of `-std=gnu++17`.

Comment: Ok, i edited code a little: [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80636d57fee0ee38). It still uses `-std=c++17` but compiles fine even with `##__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: @anton_rh That is weird. I wonder if that is GCC bug.

Comment: @user694733: not exactly a bug. It's expected (and documented) behaviour for the GCC extension. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

C++20 introduced `__VA_OPT__` as a way to optionally expand tokens in a variadic macro if the number of arguments is greater than zero.
That removes the need for the `##__VA_ARGS__` GCC extension.
If you can use that version of the standard, that should make for an elegant, compiler-unspecific solution.

> The sequence `__VA_OPT__(x)`, which is only legal in the substitution
> list of a variable-argument macro, expands to x if `__VA_ARGS__` is
> non-empty and to nothing if it is empty.

So you can simply do:
`#define DUMMY(...) Dummy("Hello" __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)`

Here is good blog article with `__VA_OPT__` in action (and more on preprocessor macros):
[https://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/blog/va-opt.html](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/%7Edm/blog/va-opt.html)

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons (it's probably a GCC bug), if you use just `#define DUMMY(...)` without other arguments, then `##__VA_ARGS__` won't work as expected (it will not remove comma if `__VA_ARGS__` is empty).

This is true only when you compile with `-std=c++17`. When you compile with `-std=gnu++17`, this doesn't happen. But in any case `##__VA_ARGS__` is GCC extension, and the code with `##__VA_ARGS__` must not be compilable with `-std=c++17` at all. But GCC allows to use GCC extensions in `-std=c++17` mode unless you set `-pedantic` flag. But it seems that GCC extensions work differently in `-std=c++17` and `-std=gnu++17` mode.

The problem however can be worked around:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename... TArgs>
void Dummy(const TArgs &...args)
{
}

namespace WA
{
    class stub_t {};

    stub_t ArgOrStub()
    {
        return {};
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto ArgOrStub(T &&t) -> decltype( std::forward<T>(t) )
    {
        return std::forward<T>(t);
    }

    template <typename... TArgs>
    void RemoveStubAndCallDummy(stub_t, TArgs &&...args)
    {
        Dummy(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename... TArgs>
    void RemoveStubAndCallDummy(TArgs &&...args)
    {
        Dummy(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    }
}

#define DUMMY(first, ...) WA::RemoveStubAndCallDummy( WA::ArgOrStub(first), ##__VA_ARGS__ )

int main()
{
    DUMMY();
}
```

When you call `DUMMY()` the `first` argument will be empty, and after preprocessing we will get `WA::ArgOrStub()` which will return `stub_t` that will later be removed by first overload of `RemoveStubAndCallDummy`. It's bulky but I couldn't fine better solution.